# Linux System goes back to vendor's default config after reboot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, busybox, sysadmin

I hope everyone is 0k.

I have embraced Linux systems for around 3-4 years now, I am not what you called an expert nor a rookie.

Anyway, I have a NAS device running BusyBox v1.20.2 - Linux version 3.2.40.

Everytime I reboot or power off/on the device, all the OS' configuration (created by me under root) gets overwritten by the default configuration (hard-coded I guess) from the vendor.

Things like: SSH banner, adding SSH public key from other devices, crontab jobs and some other minor tweaks are gone on every reboot.

My question is, what do I check within the OS' files/config? to either: A.- add my configurations to the vendor's defaults or B.- stop going to vendor's default after reboot.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your NAS probably uses a squashfs image or alike for the root file system. So you're basically modifying everything in RAM. There may be custom ROM images available for your NAS. But we cannot know, since you did not provide us with any vendor or model names.

Comment: Hey @RichardNeumann thanks for the feedback.

Sorry I did not include more info, my NAS is a Western Digital "MyCloud Mirror" model.